# angularjs : put service in other file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to put my service file in another js file but getting error

```
Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- getData
```

I have created 3 files which are :

app.js

```
app=angular.module('myApp', []); console.log("app.js loaded.");
```

service.js

```
app.service('getData',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
this.getDataFrom = function(){
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
.success(function(response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
}; }]); console.log("script loaded.");
```

index.html

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script><script src="app.js"></script><script src="service.js"></script>

<script>app.controller('customersCtrl',['$scope','getData', function($scope, getData) {
alert(getData.getDataFrom());}]);</script>
```

Basically i am trying to put [this](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp) code in different files.

Comment: just use `angular.module('myApp').service` instead of `app.service`, but I don't think you can inject $scope on service. but instantiating with `new commentDataService($scope).getComments();` should work if you `return function($scope) { ... }` in service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a $scope injected in the service. So your service should look like below:

```
app.service('getData',['$http',function($http){
   var names = null;
this.getDataFrom = function(){
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
.success(function(response) {names = response.data.records; return names;});
}; }]);
```

Comment: by removing $scope it gets the alert with 'undefined' and after that error in console that '$scope' is not defined.

Comment: did you remove "$scope." from "$scope.names" as well?

Comment: oops my mistake. Now removed that and error gone, but still it is giving undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You can't inject scope into services. It doesn't work like that, since they aren't associated with a scope.

Try rewriting your code as follows:

Remove the $scope reference in the service and the injection, and return the result of the $http.get, which is a promise

```
app.service('getData',['$http',function($http){
this.getDataFrom = function(){
    return $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
}; }]); console.log("script loaded.");
```

Then, change your controller to use the service, and when the data is fetched, to update its scope:

```
<script>app.controller('customersCtrl',['$scope','getData','commentDataService', function($scope, getData,commentDataService) {
    commentDataService.getComments().then(function(data) {
       $scope.data = data;
       console.log('the data is here!', data);
    });
alert(commentDataService.getComments());
alert(getData.getDataFrom());}]);</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it worked and to fetch data by help of this info "$scope is not associated with a scope"
finally obtained data with this code :

service.js

```
app.service('getData',['$http',function($http){
this.getDataFrom = function(){
    return $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.data.records;
    });
};}]);
```

index.html

```
    app.controller('customersCtrl', ['$scope', 'getData', function($scope, getData) {
    getData.getDataFrom().then(function(response){
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            $scope.names=response;
    });
}]);
```